# After i created apk my android app doesn't fetch any data from api

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, android-developer-api

When i run my app on my emulator or my physical device it works fine but when i create an apk and send to someone elses device it doesnt work.

That's how my build.gradle (app) file looks.

```
android {
    namespace 'com.example.movielibrary'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.movielib.movielibrary"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        buildConfig true
    }
}
```

```
object Constants {

const val BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"
const val API_KEY = "12345656987123456123"
const val IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
const val FAV_TABLE= "fav_table"
const val FAV_DATABASE= "fav_database"

const val NETWORK_TIMEOUT = 60L }
```

```
 @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBaseUrl() = BASE_URL

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun connectionTimeout() = NETWORK_TIMEOUT


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS)
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            val url = chain.request()
                .url
                .newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
                .build()

            val request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .url(url)
                .build()
            return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
        }

        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    } else {
        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .build()
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(baseUrl: String, gson: Gson, client: OkHttpClient): ApiServices =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
            .create(ApiServices::class.java)
}
```

Im trying to generate signed apk or signed bundle but api doesn't fetch any data i don't use local.properties to hide my api key or anything else how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What seems to be the issue? Could you provide more details on any errors, crashes, or malfunctioning code?

Comment: " doesnt work" is not a description we can work with. Firts make sure that you corretly handle exceptions in the network related code (don' catch and ignore exceptions, at least print them to logcat). Then install the app yourself on a physical device and collect the logcat of your app to see what is going wrong. If you still don't understand how to solve the problem edit your question and include the relevant logcat error(s) as text.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar  Well actually i dont see any crashes or errors because it works okay on my devices but when i generate signed bundle for play store or apk for some of my friends devices api doesnt work but app is working as usual i realized after play store pre-launch reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the BuildConfig.DEBUG check for adding requestInterceptor.

Comment: i have serialized name fields on my models but still having same issue :/

Comment: in order to understand the case, can you make minifyEnabled false in your release

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
it was false before i didn't change to true btw here is the code snippet.

Comment: Okay then, can you update your question with code samples from your work. because this problem is not related with manifest file

Comment: before that when i am trying to send my app to the play store console it's giving me warning like this can this be related with my problem ? 
-There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size.

Comment: I updated the post with code snippets

Comment: Hey Berkay, in provideOkHttpClient method you check the build config and add api key if its in debug mode, that's the reason its not working in release.